# C# write Xml (Attributes with http)

Tags: c#, xml, attributes

I am writing xml with c#, here is the xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<game xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
</game>
```

my code goes here:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration decl = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", null);
doc.AppendChild(decl);
XmlElement game = doc.CreateElement("game");  
doc.AppendChild(game);
XmlNode xmldocSelect = doc.SelectSingleNode("game");
//Crteate Attribute
XmlAttribute xmln = doc.CreateAttribute("xmln");
xmln.Value =":xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"";
XmlAttribute xmlns = doc.CreateAttribute("xmlns");
xmlns.Value =":xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"";
xmldocSelect.Attributes.Append(xmln);
xmldocSelect.Attributes.Append(xmlns);
```

but because the attributes has http, it doesn't work...anyone know how to write those attributes?
Thanks...

Comment: You are creating the attributes wrong. The name of the attribute is not `xmln`, that is the namespace. The name is `xsi` and value is `http://...`.

Comment: Any error that you are receiving here ?

Comment: : Unexpected symbol `http'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute names are `xsd` and `xsi` - `xmlns` is a namespace prefix that's built into the spec.

You'd create like this:

```
var doc = new XmlDocument();

var declaration = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", null);
doc.AppendChild(declaration);

var game = doc.CreateElement("game");            
game.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
game.SetAttribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
doc.AppendChild(game);
```

Unless you have good reason to stick with the old `XmlDocument` API, I'd be using LINQ to XML:

```
var doc = new XDocument(
    new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-16", null),
    new XElement("game",
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"),
        new XAttribute(XNamespace.Xmlns + "xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")));
```